# Balls in Jars probability question

Tags: probability

I wrote up a program for randomly change the order of element in an array. But I am not sure any easy way to tell whether the distribution is uniform and whether the order affect the probability. Since my array is large, I make a small one in this question.

Assume that I have 5 balls A B C D E, and 5 jars V W X Y Z
At the beginning "A is in V" ...... "E is in Z" , all balls in their jars

Now, I am at jar V, I randomly pick one of 5 jar and switch the current ball that in jar V with the ball that in the random jar. (Note: If I randomly selected jar V where I am at, there would not be any switch with other ball) In other words, ball A will have 20% to stay in jar V. Ball A will also have 20% to go to jar W,X,Y,Z respectively.

After the 1st round, I go to the 2nd jar which is jar W. I do the same thing again (randomly pick one of the five jars and switch the current ball in jar W with the ball in that newly random pick jar).

Now after 5 turns (because there are 5 jars), what are the probability for ball A to stay in jar W and ball A in W, etc. Does the order of the jar affect the probability? I can write a big tree diagram to solve, but any easier way to do this?

Moreover, I am doing a program with 200+ elements (200+ jars & 200+ balls). Does the small scale analysis fit the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $5^5=3125$ ways you can do this.
But there are $5!=120$ possible shuffles.
So there are some shuffles more likely than other shuffles, because 3125 is not a multiple of 120.
To make them equally likely,
1) swap Z with any from V to Z
2) swap Y with any from V to Y
3) swap X with any from V to X
4) swap W with any from V to W

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it there is actually a $1/5$ chance that a ball will stay in the same jar. In fact, it will always be $1/n$ chance that a specific ball will stay in the same jar, where $n$ is the number of jars and balls there are.

For example, consider having 3 jars labelled A, B and C with a ball in each jar. Now consider 1 is to swap A and A, 2 is to swap B and B, 3 is to swap C and C, 4 is to swap A and B, 5 is to swap A and C, 6 is to swap B and C.

1 1 1

1 1 2

1 1 3

1 1 4

1 1 5

1 1 6

1 2 1

1 2 2

1 2 3
and so on...

This shows all the possible combinations of swapping the balls between jars A, B and C regardless what order you do the swaps in. This is the same as how many 3-digit numbers can you make with the numbers 1 to 6, which is $6^3=216$.

The number of combinations where the ball in jar A will end up back in jar A is as shown:

1 1 1 x1

1 1 2 x3 (including 121 and 211)

1 1 3 x3

1 1 6 x3

1 2 2 x3

1 2 3 x6

1 2 6 x6

1 3 3 x3

1 3 6 x6

1 4 4 x3

1 5 5 x3

1 6 6 x3

2 2 2 x1

2 2 3 x3

2 2 6 x3

2 3 3 x3

2 3 6 x6

2 4 4 x3

2 5 5 x3

2 6 6 x3

3 3 3 x1

3 3 6 x3

3 4 4 x3

3 5 5 x3

3 6 6 x3

4 4 6 x3

5 5 6 x3

6 6 6 x1

As you can see there are 88 different combinations in a total of  that has the ball in jar A staying in jar A, regardless what order you do the swaps in. Therefore the probability of any of these combinations happening is $88/216=11/27$. You can test this with other numbers of jars and you'll always get $1/n$.

Comment: I don't think it is right. If you think about only 3 jars with 3 balls. Now ball A in jar X at the beginning, ... ball C at jar Z at the beginning. If I want to know whether ball A will stay in jar X after 3 rounds, then I can use tree diagram. After round 1, ball A in jar X is 1/3. After round 2 ball A in jar X is (ball A in jar X after 1st round and stay unaffected in the 2nd round or ball A goes to jar Y or Z in the 1st round but goes back to jar X in the 2nd round). Using this logic for the 3rd round, the probability that ball A will stay in jar X after 3 round is 10/27

Comment: @Marco: Yeah I can't seem to get it I got 11/27 for 3 balls

Comment: You are right. I missed a condition.

Comment: @Marco Well try to get the probabilities for a few number of jars and see if you get a pattern